# Is there a way to invite connectios to follow a company page via LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

LinkedIn provides a possibility to send company invites from company admin page. I checked their API and found standard invites only.
What's about an invite to follow LinkedIn page (company page)?
Where can I find API documentation if it's available?

Standard invites are possible via API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/communications/invitations?context=linkedin%2Fcompliance%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-unversioned&preserve-view=true.